# Add ${date} values to input json of curl

Tags: json, shell, curl

I've a json file which has ${date1} and ${date2} in some context. Passing this JSON file to an weburl wherein I've defined above variables. Will that work?

Shell:

```
#!/bin/sh
# Convert formating.


date1=$(date +'%d-%^h-%Y')
date2=$(date --date='tomorrow' +'%d-%^h-%Y')


echo $date1
echo $date2

curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d @patchingJsonData.json <some weburl>
```

JSON:

```
 "items": [
{

"type": "TextBlock",
"wrap": true,
"text": "Data here - ${date1} 18:30:00 to ${date2} 01:30:00"
 },
```

Comment: date2=$(date2 -d "+1 days") give me error:  Command <<date2>> not found

Comment: Nope, this won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use a tool like [xidel](/questions/tagged/xidel) to properly prepare your JSON, which you can then use for `curl`, or again `xidel`.

With `date`:

```
$ xidel -se '
  serialize(
    {
      "items":array{
        {
          "type":"TextBlock",
          "wrap":true,
          "text":"Data here - '$(date +'%d-%^h-%Y')' 18:30:00 to '$(date --date='tomorrow' +'%d-%^h-%Y')' 01:30:00"
        }
      }
    },
    {"method":"json"}
  )
'
```

With `xidel`'s own functions:

```
$ xidel -se '
  serialize(
    {
      "items":array{
        {
          "type":"TextBlock",
          "wrap":true,
          "text":concat(
            "Data here - ",
            format-date(current-date(),"[D01]-[MN,*-3]-[Y]"),
            " 18:30:00 to ",
            format-date(current-date() + duration("P1D"),"[D01]-[MN,*-3]-[Y]"),
            " 01:30:00"
          )
        }
      }
    },
    {"method":"json"}
  )
'
```

Output in both cases:

```
{"items":[{"type":"TextBlock","wrap":true,"text":"Data here - 17-APR-2021 18:30:00 to 18-APR-2021 01:30:00"}]}
```

---

### Curl (pipe)

```
$ xidel -se '
  serialize(
    [...]
  )
' | curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d@- <some weburl>
```

### Curl (variable)

```
$ eval "$(xidel -se '
  json:=serialize(
    [...]
  )
' --output-format=bash)"

$ curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "$json" "<some weburl>"
```

---

### Xidel

```
xidel -s \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-d '{
  serialize(
    [...]
  )
}' \
"<some weburl>" \
-e '$raw'
```

### Xidel (in-query)

```
$ xidel -se '
  x:request({
    "headers":"Content-Type: application/json",
    "post":serialize(
      [...]
    ),
    "url":"<some weburl>"
  })/raw
'
```

Answer (score 1):

I tested it  using
`nc -l -p 1234`  in other konsole  to receive  data from your script.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
# Convert formating.

date1=$(date +"%m-%d-%Y")
date2=$(date +"%m-%d-%Y")
#date2=$(date2 -d "+1 days")   # <-- this give me error  

#and the rest ... 

echo $date1
echo $date2

curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d @patchingJsonData.json localhost:1234
```

what i received is :

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:1234
User-Agent: curl/7.58.0
Accept: */*
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 107

"items": [{"type": "TextBlock","wrap": true,"text": "Data here - ${date1} 18:30:00 to ${date2} 01:30:00" },
```

So your script currently not works , ${date1} and ${date2} are not replaced.

Here my version using `sed`.

```
#!/bin/sh
# Convert formating.

date1=$(date +"%m-%d-%Y")
date2=$(date +"%m-%d-%Y")  #<<-- the same for now, you know what date you need

#date2=$(date2 -d "+1 days")   <<-- this not works:  date2 command not found 

echo $date1
echo $date2

json=`sed s/\$\{date1}/$date1/g patchingJsonData.json | sed s/\$\{date2}/$date1/g`

echo "$json"
#curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d @patchingJsonData.json localhost:1234
#curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data-urlencode "$json" localhost:1234
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data "$json" localhost:1234
```

Server receive and output this.

To notice : date1 and date2 are the same intentionally.
(the major porblem infact was date2)

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:1234
User-Agent: curl/7.58.0
Accept: */*
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 117

"items": [
{

"type": "TextBlock",
"wrap": true,
"text": "Data here - 04-09-2021 18:30:00 to 04-09-2021 01:30:00"
 },
```

It seems works now.

Comment: Error part update is done; but above logic of mine would work - that's the question here? Thanks

Comment: ${date1} and ${date2}  are not  replaced  as you can see in my test.  (Error a part)

Comment: i edited the answer . now it works using `sed`

Comment: Thanks `sed` works; was thinking about passing the variable so the json would do some logic. Since json doesn't process login anyhow as when curl would read the file that should read the variable and replace them with the values.